# QML Context2D how to fill two ellipses with different colors?

Tags: qml

I want to create an n segmente color bar, where its end points are semi circles. Here is my code so far:

File main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ResultBar{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        vmColorArray: ["#0000ff", "#00ff00", "#ff0000"];
        id: test;
    }

}
```

File ResultBar.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    id: resultBar
    width: 200
    height: 20

    property var vmColorArray: [];

    Canvas {
        id: rightTip
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        contextType: "2d"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onPaint: {

            if (vmColorArray.length < 2) return;

            var ctx = rightTip.getContext("2d");
            ctx.reset();

            var y = 0;
            var n = vmColorArray.length;
            var w = width/n;

            // Left end
            ctx.ellipse(0,y,height,height);
            ctx.fillStyle = vmColorArray[0];
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();

            // Right end
            ctx.ellipse(width-height,y,height,height);
            ctx.fillStyle = vmColorArray[n-1];
            ctx.fill();

            var x = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){

               if (i === 0) x = height/2;
               else x = i*w;

               var wd
               if (i === n-1) wd = w - height/2;
               else wd = w

               ctx.fillStyle = vmColorArray[i];
               ctx.fillRect(x,y,wd,height)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that coloring the right end ALSO colors the left end. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

So my question is how do I tell the canvas to fill one of the circles and THEN fill the other without refilling the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Copying ONLY the relevant code:

```
        // Left end
        ctx.fillStyle = vmColorArray[0];
        ctx.ellipse(0,y,height,height);
        ctx.fill();
        //ctx.closePath();

        // Right end
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.fillStyle = vmColorArray[n-1];
        ctx.ellipse(width-height,y,height,height);
        ctx.fill();
```

The key was to begin a new path!! Hope this helps someone!